# Mongodb document modeling - finding a reasonable approach

Tags: mongodb

I have a large asp .net app which currently uses sql server as its database. I would like to convert this app to use mongodb. One of my immediate challenges is: how to find a reasonable middle ground between the current data model, which is spread across many tables, and a document oriented approach, which would allow most, if not all of my related entities to be coalesced into a single document collection. Here is some specifics:
The business domain is IT Infrastructure, and some of the entities are "BusinessApplication", "Server", "Storage", "Network", "Workload". All of these entities are related: ...a single Business Application runs on multiple Servers; each Server has one or more Storage units associated with it; each Server has one or more Network interfaces associated with it; each Business Application can be represented by one or more Workloads, etc... So, basically it is an Object Graph. My first temptation is to create a single collection of "Workload" documents, in which each document will have multiple nested collections of sub-documents:

```
Workload:
{
    workloadId,
    workloadName,
    workloadEnvironment
    ...

    Applications:
    {
            appId,
            appName,
            appOwner,
            appType
            ...
    }

    Servers:
    {
        serverId,
        serverName,
        serverType,
        etc

        Storage:
        {
            storageUnitId,
            storageType,
            etc...
        }

        Network:
        {
            networkInterfaceId:,
            networkInterfaceType,
            ...
        }

    }


}
```

I do not have any prior experience with modeling data for mongodb, so my question is:
Is this "super nested collections" approach common and reasonable, as long as the nested entities related to one-another, or would it still be better to have some degree of normalization, and to separate "BusinessApplication" collection from "Server", from "Storage", etc...?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but I would give the following a read: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models/

Comment: Thanks! This did help by illustrating some specific patterns. I think, from my application's stand point, having a nested tree structure would align well with one of the main application concepts: "here is a Server,and here is all of the server's properties, and here is what is running on this server". having such a consolidated document structure leads to a high degree of repetition: each Server will have an array of one or more Applications with all of their attributes, so should any of those attributes change, we need to update them in all Server documents. Is this a common approach?

Comment: The best way to model for MongoDB will be based on your use cases. I would figure out what your access patterns will be and model off of that. Having duplicated data can make sense in some cases. For example in a Twitter-like system you could argue that each user could have their own copy of all tweets that they received to optimize for read performance. This of course comes at the cost of a larger data set and higher write cost.